# How to get the elements when there is an internal web page tab in powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to automate to some extent data packet analysis using nGeniusOne. nGeniusOne would open all tools in internal tabs. I have noticed that unless there is a ie navigate I am not able to find the elements. What I mean by that is that when I click on a tool and there is a dashboard which opens in an internal tab I still only have the elements from the original page and not the new tab. Can some one please help me with how to find the new elements that have been loaded.

For reference images about what I am looking at you can see 
https://www.netscout.com/product/enterprise/ngeniusone-service-assurance-platform

In the first image "Service Dashboard" is a tab that would open when you click on the link in the "All Modules" tab.

Code snippet below:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/common/NSLogin.jsp?redirect=/console")

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}   

$usernamefield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('usernameText')
$usernamefield.value = $username

$passwordfield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('passwordText')
$passwordfield.value = $password

$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.className -eq "submBtn"}
$Link.click()

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}   

$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img") | where-object {$_.alt -eq "Data Mining"}
while ($Link -eq $null){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img") | where-object {$_.alt -eq "Data Mining"}}  
$Link.click()

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}  

#Data mining opens in a new internal tab.

$i = 0
while ($Link -eq $null){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;
    $Link=$ie.Document.getElementByID("jqg_ui-id-11_ui-id-11-ns-row-4");
    Write-Host "Still not found";
    $i = $i+1;
    if($i -eq 10){break}}  
$Link.click()
```

## the above is never found even though I can see it using developer tools in IE